# What is the best way to transfer information between dags in Airflow?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

What is the best way to transfer information between dags?
Since i have a scenario where multiple dags, let’s say dag A and dag B can call dag C, I thought of 2 ways to do so:

1. XCOM - I cannot use XCOM-pull from dag C since I don’t know which dag id to give as input.
2. use context[“dag_run”].payload when calling to TriggerDagRunOperator but that solution forces me to create some kind of custom operator for each task in dag C in order to be able to use the context inside execute func and read that info.

Any other suggestions? pros/cons?
Thanks.

```
# Pass info from DAG_A \ DAG_B:
def push_info(context, dag_run_obj):
    dag_run_obj.payload = {PARAMS_KEY: {"feature_ids": 1234}}
    return dag_run_obj


trigger_DAG_C = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="trigger_DAG_C",
    trigger_dag_id="DAG_C",
    python_callable=push_info,
    dag=dag,
)


# Read the info from DAG C:
def execute():
    info = context["dag_run"].conf
```